# tabs/indents blocking code on windows server

Tags: php, windows

I have the following code and it's working great on my local xampp and test linux webhosting:

```
<?php
// include config file
include('config.php');

// get page intel
$_PAGE = switchPage($_GET);

// require language file
require_once("languages/".$_PAGE['language'].".lang.php");

// include header file
include('includes/header.inc.php');
?>

            <section id="main" class="clearfix">

                <?php
                // include correct page
                include($_PAGE['include_path']);
                ?>

            </section>

<?php
// include footer file
include('includes/footer.inc.php');
?>
```

My client has a windows server with PHP 5.2.6 installed. The hosting company claims that tabs/indents like used in the following snipet out of the code does not work on a windows php hosting.

```
            <?php
            // include correct page
            include($_PAGE['include_path']);
            ?>
```

So they claim my code is not valid PHP code.. Can someone advice please? I don't want to rewrite my code just because of all the indents I use to keep my code clean and readable ..

Comment: Your code is valid php. Define 'does not work'.

Comment: This is complete nonsense. PHP, like most modern languages, has very few stipulations about white-space and layout.

Answer (score 1):

> So they claim my code is not valid PHP code.. Can someone advice please?

On one hand, they're full of it.  It's valid code.

On the other hand, that code *could* be problematic -- if that was the opening `<?php` tag at the beginning of a file.  This is the #2 cause of the infamous "cannot send headers, headers already sent" error that PHP can generate.  Each PHP file *should not* have *any* whitespace before the opening PHP tag.

**That tag is in the middle of the document and thus is *not* a problem.**

Comment: but than I should get an error saying that " cannot send headers, .. ". I don't get shit..

Comment: @Sam, try uploading a simple file containing just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and seeing if that works.  If it doesn't, then the host is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference if you use tabs or spaces. That's still valid php.

Comment: One line answer = make it a comment plz.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what is happening is that you are ending each line with line feed character (that's what linux uses) instead of a carriage return + line feed (windows).

If the new line characters are ignored then all the code in a file will end up on one line, causing all kinds of problems (e.g. a comment like '// hello' halfway down a page will end up commenting out all the code that follows).

Try converting the file to windows format (CR+LF). You can do it with a good text editor like Notepad++.

And like others have said, how you indent your code doesn't matter.

Comment: PHP is line-ending agnostic. It'll successfully read and parse files that have LF, CRLF, or plain old CR for you prehistoric Mac fans in the audience.  (Tested in 5.3.6)

Comment: Okay, well I've had the problem I've described with files saved on a mac (CR only) on a linux server before. Can't hurt to try :)